# Java WebTestClient without SpringBoot

Tags: java, webtestclient

Is it possible to use WebTestClient for API Testing without being in a Spring OR Spring Boot project? I know RestAssured allows API Testing regardless of project.
Recieving error below

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use WebTestClient, please
> add spring-webflux to the test classpath.

The only maven import I want is spring-test:

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.31</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java:**

```
@Test
public void testData() {
    WebTestClient testClient = WebTestClient
            .bindToServer()
            .baseUrl("https://www.test.com")
            .build();

    String testBody = "testText";

    testClient.post()
            .uri("/data", "123")
            .body(Mono.just(testBody), String.class)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
```

Comment: Can't you just add `spring-webflux` with `<scope>test</scope>` to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/webtestclient.html) states

> `WebTestClient` is an HTTP client designed for testing server applications. **It wraps Spring’s `WebClient`** and uses it to perform requests but exposes a testing facade for verifying responses.

(emphasis mine). As such, it has a compile time dependency on `WebClient`. As stated by the error message you mentioned, `WebClient` is provided by the [`spring-webflux` artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux), but as [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient.html) states, you'll also need an HTTP client library to provide the client implementation.

You apparently want to [bind to standalone running web server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/webtestclient.html#webtestclient-server-config). Unfortunately, you'll need all the dependencies above to use `WebTestClient` in this way.

> without being in a Spring OR Spring Boot project

I'm not sure what you mean by *Spring Boot project*, but the dependencies above are provided as simple JARs (for example), you just need to have them on your test run's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

WebTestClient is a wrapper of WebClient, so you need WebFlux on your classpath.

If you just need a web client, why don't you just use HttpClient from the JDK?

```
String testBody = "testText";

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
   .uri(new URI("https://www.test.com/data?123"))
   .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(testBody))
   .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: http is good (aware of it), however does it allow for testing assert / expect statements?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it has build-in testing functionalities. But if you just need to assert response status or response body you can easily write it yourself. I used Hamcrest in a junit test in the past to do those sort of things.

Comment: thanks anyway, this sort of changes the question scope, my company wants me to webTestClient

Comment: I see, sorry if I couldn't help and good luck!